# Create lambda with different return type?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda

I run into this case. Assume I have a piece of code and I want to control the way how it returns:

```
bool foo() {
  auto doSomething1 = []() {
      return true;
  }
  auto doSomething2 = []() {
      // execute something but not return
  }

  auto finalLambda = condition ? doSomething1 : doSomething2

  if (case1) {
    finalLambda()
  }

  if (case2) {
    finalLambda()
  }
   ... ...

  return true;
}
```

Is this a valid (good) way to achieve this? doSomething1 returns but doSomething2 doesn't.

Comment: It's unclear from your sample why you need a lambda for this. Couldn't you just execute everything inside the if statement?

Comment: Also, are you using at least C++17, or something earlier?

Comment: @Chipster yes, I can execute in each if statement. But in that case I will duplicate lots of code if there are case1, case2... case20.

Comment: @Chipster yes c++17

Comment: I guess to achieve this, I have to templatize this, as I need to make this happen during compiling time...

Comment: 1) I got you now. That makes sense 2) because you have the option of storing it in an `std::any`. That might work for you. But that only works for C++17 or later.

Comment: Templates might work, but keep in mind `condition` would probably have to be known at compile time.

Comment: Just add 1 more layer of indirection. `if (case1) do_the_stuff(doSomething1); if (case2) do_the_stuff(doSomething2);`

Comment: `return condition ? doSomething1() : doSomething2();`

Comment: @Chipster how to do it using std::any?

Comment: @seccpur that won't work as I have many conditions.

Comment: My original thought was replacing simply replacing `auto` with [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any), though researching now that doesn't seem as trivial as I had originally thought.

Answer (score 0):

I see a problem is with your ternary operator. According to the documentation:

> A ternary operator has the following form:
>
> exp1 ? exp2 : exp3
>
> The ternary operator has return type. The return type depends on exp2, and convertibility of exp3 into exp2 as per usual\overloaded conversion rules. If they are not convertible, the compiler throws an error.

Is it possible to give some use case of that foo function? What do you expect to happen when it is called? Any possible scenario?
Is there a problem for you if all the lambda functions have the same return type? For example can you add **return false;** in the second function?

Comment: Note that's the key part for this question. I don't want to return if condition is false. I want to keep running, execute  doSomething2() until the end, then return.

Comment: What if you take out the 
`c++
  return true;
`
out of the doSomething1 lambda and instead call it in case 1 after finalLambda() expression?

Will doSomething1() always return bool and doSomething2() not return anything. Or do you expect to change these two in some point of the time?

Comment: doSomething1() will always return bool; doSomething2() won't return.

Comment: Do you expect that if the condition is true and doSomething1 is called, your foo() function will be terminated in case1 instead of going trough the rest of the cases?